# Copy data from HTML

Tags: html, excel, parsing, vba

I am trying to learn how to parse data from HTML using Excel VBA. So I found one example online which works fine but when I change URL address from `www.yahoo.com` to local HTML file on C it gives me error i.e. *Method 'busy' of object 'IwebBrowser2' failed.* Code is:

```
Sub GetBodyText()

Dim URL As String
Dim Data As String

URL = "file:///C:/test.html"

Dim ie As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate URL

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ieDoc = ie.Document

Data = ieDoc.body.innerText

'Split Data into separate lines
'or just use Range("A1")=data
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Split(Data, vbCrLf)

For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
    'Start writing in cell A1
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = myarray(i)
Next


ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
Set ieDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Will your final result be parsing a file or parsing a page?
You can pull the data from the file or the web page without loading an InternetExplorer.Application object.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, just use:

```
URL = "c:\test.html"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, But i am still getting same error. Is it because there is prompt for "Enable Active x" when i open local html file ?

Comment: Possibly, but it worked for me.  Try this: just before `ie.navigate URL`, add `ie.visible=true`.  This will actually display the IE window, so it should show you what's holding it up.